# wind barbs: how to display data series from mysql

Tags: highcharts

I read 12 of the last data (wind force and direction) directly from the mysq database in the example below.
How can I access the whole array of 12 data? In the example the data of the first array " with [value1[0],value3[0]]" is displayed correctly. As soon as I access the addresses of the whole array "[value1,value3]" only the all data of the wind strength (value1) is displayed correctly. The wind direction (value3) is not considered.

```
series: [{
type: 'windbarb',
name: 'Wind',
data: [[value1[0],value3[0]]],
```

}]

Currently I am still a Highcharts beginner. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong. I would be very happy about a solution. Many thanks in advance.
Martin

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "SELECT id, value1, value2, value3, reading_time FROM SensorData_04 order by reading_time desc limit 12";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while ($data = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $sensor_data[] = $data;
}
$readings_time = array_column($sensor_data, 'reading_time');
$value1 = json_encode(array_reverse(array_column($sensor_data, 'value1')), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
$value3 = json_encode(array_reverse(array_column($sensor_data, 'value3')), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
$reading_time = json_encode(array_reverse($readings_time), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
$result->free();
$conn->close();

    var value1 = <?php echo $value1; ?>;
    var value3 = <?php echo $value3; ?>;
    var reading_time = <?php echo $reading_time; ?>;
    
    var chartB = new Highcharts.Chart({
      chart:{ renderTo : 'chart-windbarb' },
      title: {
        text: 'Wind Barbs'
      },
      xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        categories: reading_time
      },
        series: [{
        type: 'windbarb',
        name: 'Wind',
        data: [[value1[0],value3[0]]],
      }]
    });
```

Comment: Hi @Martin Wloka, Could you create some live example with the same data structure as generated in php? You can start from: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/

Comment: Hi, I´ve updated the live example. But the true data are part of the mysql database.

Comment: Could you provide me with a link to it?

Comment: Pls. refer to https://jsfiddle.net/Martin_Wloka/3vy0g6w7/6/

Comment: The example doesn't work. You need to use only the generated js code, not php.